# Which arguments does the revert function of jQuery UI draggable accept exactly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

It is nowhere documented, see http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert

---

It shows that you can supply a function for the revert option, but it doesn't show which **arguments** this function will receive.

Comment: Not documented ...? `Multiple types supported:
Boolean:...
String:...
Function:...`

Comment: The question is which **arguments** the **revert function** accepts or receives, if you supply one..

Comment: That's what I answered, and what the ***API is showing you***. I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: No it doesn't. It shows that you can supply a function for the revert option, but it doesn't show which arguments this function will receive

Comment: Right, that's the information which should be in the question.

Comment: It is, if you read it carefully ;) the API only documents the revert option, not the revert function. (Agreed I could have worded it more precisely)

Comment: Does this help? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571919/adding-a-function-to-jquery-draggable-revert-event

Comment: Your updated title doesn't help the downvote issue you appear to be having.

Comment: also, the documentation that you linked to has the answer, under `Multiple types supported:`

Comment: Thanks PulseLab, but actually it doesn't. It isn't an official source and there are several different function signatures in the question and the answers. 'is_valid_drop' doesn't correspond with what I'm getting, also it seems to set at least two

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should learn to read source code when the documentation is not complete/satisfactory. The following invocation:

```
this.options.revert.call(this.element, dropped)
```

is on line 6055 in the non-minified [jquery-ui.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js) (and is the first result when you grep for *options.revert*)

This means that if `revert` is a function, it is invoked on the the widget element jquery object<sup>1</sup>; and it is passed `dropped` as the only argument.

`dropped` is a boolean value, which indicates whether the current `draggable` was dropped on a valid `droppable` element; as can be seen a couple of lines above it.

As the comments say: **when the `droppable` is valid and accepts the dragged element**, `dropped` holds a reference to the `droppable` jQuery DOM element (and thus converts to `true` when evaluated as a boolean)

---

1. The object a function is invoked on (in this case - the jQuery element that underlies the `draggable` widget -- is **not** passed as an argument; it is merely the context within which the function is invoked and is accessible within the function with the `this` reference.

The only *argument* the function receives is the `dropped` boolean.

Comment: Thanks man. This is the first directly useful answer and apparently you're the first person who got the question.

Comment: 'this.element' seems to refer to the draggable itself unless I didn't understand the code, not the droppable, then I saw examples where it was used as the droppable, and examples where it was used as a boolean dropped. Or 'is_valid_drop' even. I would need to access the droppable. I don't think you should have to read code to get this info though.

Comment: Actually I didn't. The comments were more helpful, I suggest editing them into the question, so it would also be useful to others :) About your comment: `this.element` refers to the object (the draggable) the `revert` function is invoked on, it is NOT an argument. It can be accessed within the function with `this`.

Comment: What's not clear about "EDIT It shows that you can supply a function for the revert option, but it doesn't show which **arguments** this function will receive" ?

Comment: What do you mean "it is NOT an argument"? Oh I get it, because of the .call() semantics? SEE this is why I expect documentation for that. Can't expect a standard user of a jquery function to read and understand its intricate code ;)

Comment: @user3280015 Edited in post now.

Comment: Just for the records, the returned `dropped` is **not** a boolean. It is false if the current draggable was dropped on a valid droppable element, and otherwise it is the droppable object it was dropped on itself. So much for documentation by code ;-)