# JQuery UI Draggable Multiple revert Options

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

The JQuery UI `draggable` widget has a `revert` options which determines under what circumstances the dragged element should revert back to its initial location.

The [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert) specifies that the string `"invalid"` may be provided in which case the dragged element reverts to its original location if not dropped on a `droppable` widget. Another option is to provide `revert` with a function which will determine whether the widget should revert when the dragging stops.

In my situation, I'd like both of these behaviors; I want the widget to revert if dropped on a non-droppable element, but I also want to do some on-the-fly custom validation, failure of which should result in a revert. How can I incorporate both of these functionalities?

Comment: Not a dup, but I think this question will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571919/adding-a-function-to-jquery-draggable-revert-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `revert` is a function, the first argument passed to it is the `droppable` or `sortable` widget it was dropped on, if one exists, or `false` otherwise. For example:

```
$(elt).draggable({
    revert: function(dropped) {
        var result = false;
        // dropped can safely be typecast to boolean
        // if you want to call jquery functions on it check for "false" first
        result = customLogic || (dropped && $(dropped).is(".valid-droppable-class") ); 
        return result;
    }
});
```

Using `revert:"invalid"` is equivalent to `revert: function(dropped) { return dropped; }`

Comment: Yes, I figured this out. Turns out I get stuck with the fact that my custom validation logic happens asynchronously, so I have to bark up a different tree for this one.