# How to fire event after revert is complete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Unlike with setter `$( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "revert", function(){return true} );` , which fire function in the begging of the revert, I need to fire an event with a function when revert of draggable is complete.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571919/adding-a-function-to-jquery-draggable-revert-event?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no, but it's not what I need. In firs answer there is jsfiddle  example with duck and a bout, when you release duck div it instantly changes colour, what I need is for it to change after it lands back into place